# How to group common parameters when calling the same SQL Server stored procedures multiple times?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2

I am in the process of writing a SQL query file for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 which will call a number of stored procedures to create a merge publication. The baseline script was generated through the New Publication Wizard in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

The "problem" I am facing is that when creating the merge articles using the `sp_addmergearticle` stored procedure, I need to define a number of parameters which are common to all merge articles, such as the publication name, source owner, destination owner and so on.

The question, then: Is there a way to group a collection of named parameters and supply them in a common fashion so administering changes to these parameters would be simpler?

For example, consider the following query snippet:

```
use [MyDatabase]
exec sp_addmergearticle @publication=N'MyPub', 
                        @article=N'MyTable#1', 
                        @source_object=N'MyTable#1', 
                        @source_owner=N'TheOwner', 
                        @destination_owner=N'TheOwner',
                        @allow_interactive_resolver=N'true'

exec sp_addmergearticle @publication=N'MyPub', 
                        @article=N'MyTable#2', 
                        @source_object=N'MyTable#2', 
                        @source_owner=N'TheOwner', 
                        @destination_owner=N'TheOwner',
                        @allow_interactive_resolver=N'true'

etc...

GO
```

Now, I would like to make this piece of script easier to read and maintain so that the `sp_addmergearticle` calls would take a set of parameters which are common to all calls, and some specific parameters which are call-specific.

For example, like this:

```
use [MyDatabase]

-- Common parameters for all merge articles
DECLARE @common_parameters
-- @publication=N'MyPub'
-- @source_owner=N'TheOwner', 
-- @destination_owner=N'TheOwner',
-- @allow_interactive_resolver=N'true'

exec sp_addmergearticle @common_parameters, 
                        @article=N'MyTable#1', 
                        @source_object=N'MyTable#1', 

exec sp_addmergearticle @common_parameters,
                        @article=N'MyTable#2', 
                        @source_object=N'MyTable#2', 

etc...

GO
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? If possible, what means should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use local variables for some values (these can't, unfortunately, cross batch boundaries):

```
use [MyDatabase]

-- Common parameters for all merge articles
DECLARE @publication sysname
DECLARE @source_owner sysname 
DECLARE @destination_owner sysname
DECLARE @allow_interactive_resolver nvarchar(5)
select @publication=N'MyPub',
       @source_owner=N'TheOwner', 
       @destination_owner=N'TheOwner',
       @allow_interactive_resolver=N'true'

exec sp_addmergearticle @publication=@publication,
                        @source_owner=@source_owner, 
                        @destination_owner=@destination_owner,
                        @allow_interactive_resolver=@allow_interactive_resolver,
                        @article=N'MyTable#1', 
                        @source_object=N'MyTable#1', 

exec sp_addmergearticle @publication=@publication,
                        @source_owner=@source_owner, 
                        @destination_owner=@destination_owner,
                        @allow_interactive_resolver=@allow_interactive_resolver,
                        @article=N'MyTable#2', 
                        @source_object=N'MyTable#2',
```

And then at least there's only one place that these need to be updated, as required.

Comment: I was afraid that this is the only approach, and was somewhat hoping that there would've been a better one. But guess this is what I have to work with.